# can't view wampserver using the hostname

Tags: wamp

I've installed WAMPserver 2.4 on a Windows 7.1 PC.

I clicked on the WAMPserver icon in the system tray, selected "put online".

If I load `http://hostname/` (where hostname is my computer's name) in my browser, I receive the error `403 Forbidden`

What do I need to do to make my WAMPserver public?
(within the LAN and WAN)

**Edit**: Within httpd.conf, there is this section:

```
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
# 
ServerName localhost
```

If I changed localhost to my hostname, restarted Apache, the same error remained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I am running WAMP 2.4.x, I edit my httpd.conf, and find:

```
# onlineoffline tag - don't remove
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Allow from ::1
  Allow from localhost
```

and add:

```
 Allow from 10.6.0.138
 Allow from 10.2.26
```

My IP address is 10.6.0.138.

My colleague's IP address is 10.2.26.*

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess it's only listening on 127.0.0.1:80.

Open the apache-config (typical names are httpd.conf, apache.conf...) and search for a line:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

then edit that line to

```
Listen 80
```

or

```
Listen your.dom.ain:80
```

Please take a look at the apache documentation for more information.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/bind.html

Comment: It was already listed as `Listen 80` so I changed it do `Listen hostname:80`, restarted Apache and the same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

allow your host from apache httpd configuration file

default allow deny in httpd.conf file

```
 Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

Add your host in allow list

```
Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from all
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
     Allow from localhost
     Allow from yourhost
</Directory>
```

Comment: I added `Allow from yourhost`, restarted Apache, and the same error occurred.

Comment: you just added simply yourhost or actual your host?

Comment: My host name...

Answer (score 0):

If configuring your .conf file doesn't work.

You need to edit your host file. By going to: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc. It "may" work

Uncomment the `127.0.0.1       localhost` line and remove the line below it.

So your host file will look like this

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
    127.0.0.1       localhost
```

delete your old or put your old host file as ".OLD".
or you can copy and replace. Hope it works for you. :))

Comment: I tried this, restarted Apache, and the error remained.  I added `127.0.0.1 hostname` at the end with no difference.